# Using Automapper CreateMap to concatenate elements

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have the following EF classes:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual List<RequestLinked> RequestLinkeds { get; set; }
}

public class RequestLinked
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Request")]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("RequestRelated")]
    public int RequestRelatedID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual Request RequestRelated { get; set; }
}
```

I created a DTO like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    ...
    [DataMember]
    public string RequestRelatedIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to use automapper fo fill my DTO object. I need to fill `RequestRelatedIDs` with all elements from `RequestLinkeds.RequestRelatedID` by concatenate all elements inside 1 string.

I tried this:

```
CreateMap<Request, RequestDTO>()
  .ForMember(x => x.RequestRelatedIDs, o => o.MapFrom(src => string.Join(", ", src.RequestLinkeds.Select(x => x.RequestRelatedID));
```

But the `Select` method is red highlighted: System.Collections.Generic.List< PLATON.Domain.Models.RequestLinked >' does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Why is that not possible to perform a select? An alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: Found: needed `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Just a word of warning - look at the SQL getting generated here. It might be insane.